# Which probability distribution is this?

Tags: probability-distributions

Suppose we draw a number $x$ uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$, what is then the following distribution. Furthermore, calculate $F(y)$ and $f(y)$.

$$y = \dfrac{x}{1-x}$$

This is a question I came across. Looks very simple, but I just simply do not know. Especially the functions aren't specified anywhere. Do they have a general meaning?

Comment: $F$ would be the cumulative distribution function of $y$, and $f$ the corresponding density (i.e., $f=F'$).

Comment: $f(y)$ and $F(y)$ typically denote the probability density and cumulative density function of a random variable. You surely did not see such an underspecified question in any book/forum related to mathematics?

Comment: @mathse Underspecified? No (but badly formulated, yes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that, for every $y\geqslant0$,
$$[Y\leqslant y]=[X\leqslant y/(1+y)],
$$
hence
$$
F(y)=y/(1+y),\qquad f(y)=\mathbf 1_{y\gt0}/(1+y)^2$$

Comment: I have a feeling that this $y$ does not really have a particular name. Is this some known distribution?

Comment: @Did. Given your answer, now I can figure out what the question should have been :). The question should have been formulated, in my opinion, as: given that $X$ is a uniformly distributed RV on $[0,1]$, what is the distribution of $Y=\frac{X}{1-X}$.

Comment: @user61001: wikipedia lists three examples of this type under the category "functions of random variables" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable#Functions_of_random_variables. Your distribution is not there, though...